# Unplanned repeated key presses

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, keyboard

Repeated key presses are being registered by the Macbook Pro (running OSX 10.6.8) that I'm using.

For example, if this had happened in the above sentence, on pressing 'k' it would keep pressing 'k' several times unless I type some other key and looked like this: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkey.

This does not happen all the time but is very annoying. Have seen this happen in 2 text editors that I use: Komodo IDE, vi. And, also once while composing a message in Gmail. So I guess this is a problem with the Mac internals and not that of a particular application.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: What happens when you plug in an external USB keyboard and type with that instead?

Comment: @Wheat Williams: Haven't tried that as of yet. Will give that a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, it doesn't look like a software problem, since it's happening randomly on multiple applications.

So it looks like an hardware problem. Your best solution is to go to an Apple Store to get it looked at.

Answer (score 0):

You could upgrade to Lion, as the behaviour for extended key presses has changed.  If I hold down the C key instead of giving me the old "cccccccc" etc thing, it provides a small popover menu thing to allow me to select alternative accented letter "c"s, like this ç/ć/č and so on.  You select them by clicking or hitting the associated number that is listed under them.  Alternatively if you just ignore it, and then press another key (so long as it is not 1/2/3 etc or a number that associated with one of the accented characters) it will cancel the while thing and just let you type normally.  It's not a great fix, I admit, but it would be a workaround, whereby the popup would indicate a stuck key, but you would not fill your screen with a random number of extra letters that you would then need to delete.